# C.CS50 Purality assignment , printing the winner of an election

Tags: c, cs50

I've been trying in the last few days to debug this program but I still can't find a solution so I hope you can help me with that.

This program should print the winners(s) of an election. I'm assigned only to implement the `print_winner` and vote functions.

If the name inputted matches one of the names of the candidates in the election (the candidates are the command line arguments), then the vote function should update that candidate’s vote total to account for the new vote and return true. If not it should return false. The problems seems to be just in counting votes, the boolean part works fine.

The `print_winner` function should print out the name(s) of the candidate(s) who received the most votes in the election, and then print a newline.

Here is my code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Max number of candidates
#define MAX 9

// Candidates have name and vote count
typedef struct {
    string name;
    int votes;
} candidate;

// Array of candidates
candidate candidates[MAX];

// Number of candidates
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(string name, int argc, string argv[]);
void print_winner(string name, string argv[], int argc, int voter);

int main(int argc, string argv[]) {
    string name;
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Usage: plurality [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX) {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++) {
        candidates[i].name = argv[i + 1];
        candidates[i].votes = 0;
    }

    int voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");

    // Loop over all voters
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++) {
        name = get_string("Vote: ");

        // Check for invalid vote
        if (!vote(name, argc, argv)) {
            printf("Invalid vote.\n");
        }
    }

    // Display winner of election
    print_winner(name, argv, argc, voter_count);
}

// Update vote totals given a new vote
bool vote(string name, int argc, string argv[]) {
    // TODO
    int voter_count = argc - 1;
    int i, j;
    candidate f[candidate_count];
    for (i = 0; i < voter_count; i++) {
        f[i].name = name;
        f[i].votes = 0;
        for (j = 1; j < argc; j++) {
            if (strcmp(name, argv[j]) == 0) {
               return true;
               f[i].votes = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < voter_count; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < voter_count; j++) {
            if (i != j) {
                if (strcmp(f[i].name, f[j].name) == 0) {
                    f[i].votes = f[i].votes + 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Print the winner (or winners) of the election
void print_winner(string name, string argv[], int argc, int voter) {
    // TODO
    int voter_count = argc - 1;
    int i, j;
    candidate f[candidate_count];
    for (i = 0; i < voter_count; i++) {
        f[i].name = name;
        f[i].votes = 0;
        for (j = 1; j < argc; j++) {
            if (strcmp(name, argv[j]) == 0) {
               f[i].votes = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < voter_count; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < voter_count; j++) {
            if (i != j) {
                if (strcmp(f[i].name, f[j].name) == 0) {
                    f[i].votes = f[i].votes + 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    int max = f[0].votes;
    j = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < voter_count; i++) {
        if (f[i].votes > max) {
            max = f[i].votes;
            j = i;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < voter_count; i++) {
        if (max == f[i].votes) {
            printf("%s\n", f[i].name);
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Your post does not ask a question, other than a general request to debug your program, which is too broad. You should provide a [mre], including sample input that demonstrates a problem, the output you observe, and the output you expect instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some problems in your code:

- The functions `vote()` and `print_winner()` shuld not take `argc` and `argv` but operate on the global array `candidates`.
- Furthermore, a single loop suffices to handle a vote and it is also simple to determine the winner(s). The code in `vote()` and `print_winner()` is too complicated and does not handle any meaningful data.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Max number of candidates
#define MAX 9

// Candidates have name and vote count
typedef struct {
    string name;
    int votes;
} candidate;

// Array of candidates
candidate candidates[MAX];

// Number of candidates
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(string name);
void print_winners(void);

int main(int argc, string argv[]) {
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Usage: plurality candidate [...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX) {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++) {
        candidates[i].name = argv[i + 1];
        candidates[i].votes = 0;
    }

    int voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");

    // Loop over all voters
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++) {
        string name = get_string("Vote: ");

        // Check for invalid vote
        if (!vote(name)) {
            printf("Invalid vote: %s\n", name);
        }
    }

    // Display winner of election
    print_winners();
    return 0;
}

// Update vote totals given a new vote
bool vote(string name) {
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++) {
        if (strcmp(candidates[i].name, name) == 0) {
            candidates[i].votes += 1;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false; // no such candidate
}

// Print the winner (or winners) of the election
void print_winners(void) {
    int max_votes = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++) {
        if (candidates[i].votes > max_votes) {
            max_votes = candidates[i].votes;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++) {
        if (candidates[i].votes == max_votes) {
            printf("%s\n", candidates[i].name);
        }
    }
}
```